# Failing to catch HTTP 500 error in fetch api

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

Here is a fragment of my client-side source code. In this particular instance the server-side code logged an error in a .catch clause and the POST  reports an error 500 in the Chrome developer tools console. But if I set a breakpoint on the "console.error" line, it is never hit. What is going on here, and what would be the best way to handle it so I could provide a tailored response to the user?

```
fetch("http://localhost:3003/playlist", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(content),
  headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
})
.then((result) => {
  if (result == "Empty playlist") {
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    console.log("Saved");
  }
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.error(e.message)
});
```

> POST http://localhost:3003/playlist 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Consult your logs for the *cause* of the 500 error.